# Cannot GET / with gulp-connect-php

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, gulp

I'm using [gulp-connect-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-php) to try and run a php server locally with BrowserSync. Here's my gulp config file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect-php'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('connect-sync', function() {
  connect.server({}, function (){
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "app"
        },
     // proxy: '127.0.0.1:8000'
    });
  });

  gulp.watch('**/*.php').on('change', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
  });
});

gulp.task( 'default', [ 'connect-sync' ] )
```

The above code works when I have a index.html file in my app directory but when I replace it with an index.php file I get the following message:

> Cannot GET /

Not exactly sure what i've done wrong here?

Comment: Just point your browser to http://localhost:3000/index.php

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question is that php serve is not recognizing .php files. There are 2 ways to get this work.

Apache (httpd.conf), search for DirectoryIndex and replace the line with this (will only work if you have dir_module enabled, but that's default on most installs) or add index.php

```
 DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm
```

or
Create a .htaccess file in your web root.
Add the line...

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a index filename, add and `index` object to `server`.

```
...
browserSync({
    server: {
        baseDir: "app",
        index: "/index.php"
    },
});
...
```

You could also set browserSync startpage to /index.php instead of /
**Edit** I couldn't get `startPath` to work, so use `index` as in the example above.

```
...
browserSync({
    server: {
        baseDir: "app"
    },
    startPath: "/index.php"
});
...
```

@pramod-patil I don't think Apache directions will help here, since browserSync doesn't use Apache for serving PHP.